# "In the platform" or "on the platform"?

Tags: prepositions

I don't mean such platforms as Netflix, Youtube or social media platforms.
If this is a marketing automation platform (in other words - software), can we say "in the platform"?

> ***In the*** HubSpot Marketing Automation ***platform***, you can set up such automation workflows as a welcome email, abandoned cart emails or onboarding workflow.

Comment: It depends - what are you trying to say?

Comment: @psmears For example, "In the HubSpot Marketing Automation, you can set up such automation workflows as a welcome email, abandoned cart emails or onboarding workflow".

Comment: Thanks Polina, that's useful :) Where did you want to put "(in/on) the platform" in that sentence? Can you edit your question to include the example(s)? That will help people give good answers.

Comment: @psmears My fault :)
"In the HubSpot Marketing Automation platform, you can set up such automation workflows as a welcome email, abandoned cart emails or onboarding workflow".

Comment: I think this *specific* use of ***platform*** *([an application or website that serves as a base from which a service is provided](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platform))* is quite new, so the "preferred" preposition usage hasn't exactly settled down yet. It's by extension from the already metaphoric sense *a means or opportunity to communicate ideas or information to a group of people* (alluding to someone ***standing ON a raised platform*** to address a crowd), but arguably the "container metaphor" allusion *(**IN**)* suits the modern meaning better.

Comment: Semantically speaking, in this context you're actually working ***in*** an environment, rather than ***on*** a "platform". Witness how the OP here simply writes "**In** the HubSpot Marketing Automation [platform]" in a comment, without thinking about the grammar as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for the answer. Now it became clear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your helpful comments reveal why this question is actually worth keeping in our EL&U library. If only someone (nudge nudge) would copy your two comments and the link into the answer box. ;-)

Comment: I'd probably strike "in" and use "with" instead. You're also missing an oxford comma in your example, if you care about that.

Comment: @GammaGames: Yes, or "using"

Comment: *In* and *on* are both valid, but they mean different things. An analogy to *platform* in this context is a *theatrical set*. The actors work *on the set*. The stagehands are not *on set* during the performance, but could be *in the set* in order to perform some function.

Comment: My view as a software developer: IN the platform would refer to actions doable by the developer or implementer. ON the platform would refer to actions doable by users of the service.

Answer (score 14):

I think this specific use of [***platform***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platform) *(an application or website that serves as a base from which a service is provided)* is quite new, so the "preferred" preposition usage hasn't exactly settled down yet. It's by extension from the already metaphoric sense *a means or opportunity to communicate ideas or information to a group of people* (alluding to someone standing ***ON*** a raised platform to address a crowd), but arguably the "container metaphor" allusion *(**IN**)* suits the modern meaning better.

Semantically speaking, the specified context involves actually working ***in** an environment*, rather than ***on** a "platform"*. And it's worth pointing out that when the OP was simply trying to present an "example" context in *two* comments, they quite naturally wrote ***In** the HubSpot Marketing Automation [platform] you can [do things]* when all they wanted to do was *communicate* (without thinking about the "grammar" as such).

---

TL;DR
This is a stylistic choice, not a matter of grammatical rules. But my choice would always be for ***in*** here, because *semantically* speaking, the metaphoric usage refers to *a working environment* (***container*** metaphor) rather than a position of high visibility for addressing a wider audience (***[raised] surface*** metaphor).

Comment: Very well expressed! I am glad you were attracted to this question, just as I was. I agree with Chappo that it definitely belongs on EL&U. Grateful he prompted you to answer.

Comment: Yes, looking more closely at your answer than I did first time around, I now think we're essentially saying the same thing. When seen as a ***working environment***, you might feasibly work ***in** a platform* (focus on the technicians), but as a ***marketing channel** [of communication]*, you'd more naturally interact with your customer base ***on** the platform* (where the customers can "see" you, hopefully up there raised above the competition).

Comment: Yes, we posted almost simultaneously, and we practically agree.

Comment: +100 for the "environment" comment - it's quite relevant here.  We use "in" very often when talking about working with software:  "In Excel, one can sort by date..."

Comment: In this context, platform has nothing to do with heightened *visibility.* The platform is a scaffold or stage that gives extends your reach farther and faster than starting from ground level. Further, you can extend the stage metaphor to cover the facilities it offers. Just as lighting, traps, sound, and rigging are ready to build upon for any production, a computing platform provides much of the basic infrastructure upon which any application could be built. The platform is very much about raising the capability of what you build *on* it, not *in* it.

Comment: Googling OP's first name it seems to be feminine, so I suspect you've used the wrong pronouns here. Since this is English Language & Usage I suggest you use singular "they" in future :)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree - think about replacing "platform" with one specific platform.  You'd rarely say "*I asked a question **in** Stack Exchange*".  More likely it would be "*I asked a question **on** Stack Exchange*".

Answer (score 6):

Personally as a Software Engineer I use it like this:

*ON the platform*, when I am actually using the platform.
Example: "I am on the marketing platform right now looking at data"

*IN the platform*, when I am "inside" of the platform and change things programatically or change settings etc.
Example: "I am in the marketing platform changing parameters"

Hope that makes somewhat sense?

Answer (score 5):

*In the platform* is *[less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20platform%2C%20on%20the%20platform&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20platform%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20platform%3B%2Cc0)* than *on the platform*, and in most of the examples found with *in*, ***platform*** is an attributive noun:

> in the Platform Era; in the platform economy; in the platform society ([Googlesearch](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20platform%22&sxsrf=ALeKk02yZav5GHRpNNRoj8X8iocDsV27hw:1628507512968&ei=eA0RYZzbOoql1fAP5MmcyAI&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwic98ue56PyAhWKUhUIHeQkByk4ChDy0wN6BAgBEDg&biw=1372&bih=661))

So, although the GNgram comparison between the two is not accurate, it does point to the fact that ***in the platform*** is still rare.

There is a particular instance where you can use ***in the platform*** in the way you suggest, when there are technical changes done ***in the structure or system*** of that platform.

***On the platform*** suggests that it is up and running and something occurs ***on it***, as we say that something occurs ***online***. When you do something ***on a site***, we assume that the site has been set up and functioning, and you use the services/functions it offers. To change something ***in*** its structure as a developer, would rather be described by the preposition ***in***.

Your sentence is an instance of a technical change ***in** the platform*, so I would definitely go and use it:

> ***In*** the HubSpot Marketing Automation ***platform***, you can *set up such automation workflows* as a welcome email, abandoned cart emails or onboarding workflow.

You set up an automation in the platform, it is a change ***in its functions, in its structure***, so that people can use these functions while they are active ***on the platform.***

However, as showed in the comments, the use of *in* is starting to overlap with that of *on* with "platform", as the concept of *virtual space* is becoming more solid.

Answer (score 2):

Of those two, **on the platform** is more correct (especially when referring to a physical platform).

In context, however, that word choice is better avoided entirely with something like **using the platform** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reading is that “platform” is being used as a synonym for “app” or “software.” You’re performing a task *in* a platform, like one does something *in* or *within* or *with* an application or interface.  So, maybe if you get a thousand karma for your question, you do that *on* StackExchange, but if you change your user profile, you do that either *in* or *on* or *with* the platform.

With a physical platform, you always say “on” (unless there’s some kind of chamber or hollow space inside it that one can be within).

Answer (score 0):

Many moons ago, I did a stint in a glorified data-entry position, where it was definitely "perform work/enter data, etc. ON the platform". But it having been cobbled together on the cheap, the platform's administrators/programmers would frequently have to make changes IN/TO the platform itself...

So it seems the conceptual metaphor "platform" (a raised level providing support) only applies to users: the ones the platform supports. However, as someone already mentioned, "in the platform" across the board seems to be making headway - I guess analogous to "in the app/program" - linguistic consistency trumps figures of speech. And I'd say most people these days spend a lot more time on online platforms than physical ones (unless they work on a oil rig).

The debate on which prepositional collocations hold more water is largely moot, because these are by and large merely set conventions that frequently shift around, varying even between dialects of the same language (like UK/US "at/on the weekend, "in/at school" "get of/of off the roof).